# Parsing RTP stream to get I frame of MPEG4 codec from Panasonic camera

Tags: c, rtsp, rtp, mpeg-4

I'm using ffmpeg to record RTSP MPEG4 stream from camera

1. RTSP has been established by calling avformat_open_input function
2. Frame is received from the camera with `av_read_packet`(contest, &***packet***) and it is stored in AVPacket structure.
3. Now I want to parse this frame to determine which is I frame before it is stored to file. 
   Using `avcodec_decode_video` func which might help me in this case but because there is a delay decoding so it is not good choise for me. Anyway, I want to use another way

Simply I think packet.data contains a RTP format which includes RTP header + RTP data.

I've looked into some other theads such as: [how to process draw data packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i) and [parsing MPEG-4 from rtp packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082080/parsing-mpeg4-frames-from-rtp-packets). Actually they look very close what I need and maybe I did something wrong.Therefore, I still cannot figure out where is 12 bytes for RTP header in ***packet***.data and then what I realy need is I, P or B video object plane info.

Trying to parse the RTP format but it seems ***packet***.data either contains some extra information more than a pure RTP format or doesn't contain RTP header. I'm not sure.

**Shotly:**

```
How can I parse the frame to get frame info (I, P or B) in AVPacket
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use FFmpeg but according [to the doc](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVPacket.html#aaf4fe58dfcc7c232c1f2268b539d8367) you can access to the raw data with AVPacket.data

At this point maybe you can just do this:

```
int nalType = packet->data[0] & 0x1F;
if (naType == 5) // iFrame
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my problem is that I forgot to check type of data (audio or video frame). I was looking the I frame in audio stream and compare with video MPEG4 format that why's I didn't parse the frame properly. I hope no one get the same problem like me